# Loading XML with jQuery - output printing over itself on one line

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml

I am loading the contents of an XML file using jQuery, when the user selects a play they are supposed to get a list of all the Acts and what Scenes they contain.

However if there is a long scene title when it reaches the end of the div instead of printing the remaining amount on a new line it is printing over itself on the same line.

[image: Scene problem]

This is the function I am using to load the play overview from the XML:

```
function displayOverview(play_dom) {
  current_play_dom = play_dom;
  currentContext = $("PLAY", current_play_dom);
  $("#mainOutput").empty();
  $("#mainOutput").append('<p class="dramatis">' + $("PLAY>PERSONAE>TITLE", current_play_dom).text() + '</p>');
  $("PLAY>ACT", current_play_dom).each(function (actNo_jq) {
    var current_act = $(this);
    var actNo_ws = actNo_jq + 1;
    $("#mainOutput").append('<p class="actTitle link"' + 'id="' + actNo_ws + '">' + $("TITLE:first", current_act).text() + "<p>");
    $("SCENE", current_act).each(function (sceneNo_jq) {
      var current_scene = $(this);
      var sceneNo_ws = sceneNo_jq + 1;
      $("#mainOutput").append('<p class="sceneTitle link"' + 'id="' + actNo_ws + "_" + sceneNo_ws + '">' + $("TITLE:first", current_scene).text() + "<p>");
    });
  });
  contextInfo();
}
```

CSS that is being applied directly:

```
.sceneTitle {
  font-size: 14px; 
  text-indent: 3.0em;
  line-height: 25%;
}

.link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

CSS of the div it is appended to:

```
#mainOutput { 
  float: left;
  height: 472px;
  width: 756px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: -100px;
  font-family: Intro;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4b3f2e;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the line-height to something more suitable. 100% might help.

```
.sceneTitle {
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was rather simple. Only problem is the `text-indent` is not applied to the new line when it wraps round.

Comment: Instead of using text-indent you could set padding on the left of the sceneTitle class.